# MVVMCROSS Binding TimeSyncProblem

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've got a special problem with binding data to an itemsource of an mvxtablieviewsource.
I'm trying to generate a list of favorites, which are generated in the core by clicking on a different tablview.

Normally I get the databinding working like this: (Just basic structure)

**controller:**

```
var source = new MySource(TableView);

this.AddBindings(new Dictionary<object, string>
                    {
                    {source, "ItemsSource Favs"}

                        });
```

**Source:**

```
private List<FavModel> _favs;

public override IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return _favs; }

            set
            {                
                    _favs = (List<FavModel>)value;
                    ReloadTableData();

            }
        }

protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
        {
            var cell = new AdFavCell();         
            cell.TextLabel.Text = ((FavModel)item).Display;
            return cell;


        }
```

Normally it works really great but no in this case where i generate the data by reacting on users touch, I've got this strange failure;

- When I set a breakpoint in the setter of the ItemsSource, and wait for a while then it works correctly.
- When I run without a breakpoint the tableview keeps empty.

I also figured out that if I insert a manually pause in the setter then it works too:

**Setter with pause:**

```
public override IEnumerable ItemsSource
            {
                get { return _mydata; }

                set
                {                
                        _favs = (List<FavModel>)value;
                        ReloadTableData();
                        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                }
            }
```

I also tried to do a delaybinding, but it didn't work.

Have anyone an idea where the problem is?

Edit:

Here some additional Information:

**How the Data is generated:**

I've got a tableview with content and depending on a longclick on a cell, I create a popumenu where you can add your favorites.

**Detecting the longclick:**

```
protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
        {


            MvxTableViewCell cell = null;


            if (item is SoccerEventListModel)
            {

                cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(this.CellIdentifier) as SoccerEvent;

                if (cell == null)
                {

                    cell = new SoccerEvent((SoccerEventListModel)item);
                    cell.AddGestureRecognizer(new UILongPressGestureRecognizer((e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
                        {

                            var command = ItemLongClickCommand;
                            if (command != null)
                                command.Execute(item);
                        }
                    }));

                    return cell;

                }

            }
        }
```

**Binding the Longclick to the core:**

```
EventListViewModel.EventFavViewCallbackEvent += EventListViewModel_EventFavViewCallbackEvent;



        void EventListViewModel_EventFavViewCallbackEvent(EventModel e)
        {

                var StoreFav = new EventFavoritesView { ViewModel = new EventFavoritesViewModel { ID = e.ID } };

                View.Add(StoreFav.View);



        }
```

Depending on the ID of the cell, it creates the list of the favorites by sending a request to our server.

**Update:**

```
private long _id;
        public long ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ID); Update(); }
        }
```

When the data is received a RaisePropertyChanged() should make the view to reload its content.

```
private List<FavModel> _favs;
        public List<FavModel> Favs
        {
            get { return _favs; }
            set { _favs = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Favs); }
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class EventFavoritesViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private readonly EventFavoritesService _eventFavoriteService;
        private readonly UserFavoritesService _userFavoriteService;

        private long _id;
        public long ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ID); Update(); }
        }

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Title); }
        }

        private List<FavModel> _favs;
        public List<FavModel> Favs
        {
            get { return _favs; }
            set { _favs = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Favs); }
        }

        private MvxCommand<FavModel> _itemSelectedCommand;
        public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _itemSelectedCommand = _itemSelectedCommand ?? new MvxCommand<FavModel>(ToggleFav);
                return _itemSelectedCommand;
            }
        }

        public void Init(long eventID)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace("We get the details", Logger.Errorlevel.Debug);
            ID = eventID;
        }

        public EventFavoritesViewModel()
        {
            _eventFavoriteService = new EventFavoritesService(UpdateEventFav);
            _userFavoriteService = new UserFavoritesService(UpdateUserFav);
        }

        private void UpdateUserFav(Fav[] favlist)
        {
            MvxMessenger.Publish(new UserFavUpdateMessage(this, favlist));
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            Favs = _eventFavoriteService.GetFavforEvent(ID).MapToFavs();
        }

        private void UpdateEventFav(Fav[] favlist)
        {
            Favs = favlist.MapToFavs();
        }

        private void ToggleFav(FavModel item)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace("Got Item: " + item.Display);
            item.NewSubscription = !item.NewSubscription;
        }

        private IMvxMessenger MvxMessenger
        {
            get
            {
                return Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
            }
        }

        public void SaveFavs()
        {
            foreach (var fav in Favs)
            {
                if (fav.AlreadySubscribed != fav.NewSubscription)
                {
                    if (fav.NewSubscription)
                        _userFavoriteService.PutToUserFavorites(fav.MapToFav());
                    else
                        _userFavoriteService.DeleteFromUserFavorites(fav.MapToFav());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this is enough information, otherwise just tell me.:-)
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide  more information on what "generating data by responding to users touch" means - why is the data not available at start - how is the data signalled as available?

Comment: Sorry - still not sure I have the picture. I can't see where the `MyData` in `{source, "ItemsSource MyData"}` is updated in the ViewModel.

Comment: Ok changed the types of my first Post. When a longclick is detected it creates a new FavoritesView and setting the Viewmodel to his correspending Viewmodel. Then the Viewmodel updates the data when the value of the ID is changed. So the ViewModel calls then Update() and loads the new Data in _favs, which raise a propertychanged after it's value has been changed.

Comment: Favs is binded to the ItemSource of the TableView.

Comment: I have added now the hole ViewmodelCode. Hope that helps.